# how to prove $\prod_{k=1}^{p-1} \sin(\frac{\pi k}{p}) = \frac{p}{2^{p-1}}$?

Tags: number-theory, trigonometry

i found this relation whilst trying to evaluate the norm (over $\mathbb{Q}$) of $1-\zeta$ for $\zeta$ a primitive $p$-th root of unity ($p$ supposed prime)
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{p-1} \sin(\frac{\pi k}{p}) = \frac{p}{2^{p-1}}
$$
as yet i have no means of proving it. any suggestions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- Kindly [see this article](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Resources/Papers/TrigIdent.pdf) page number $5$.

Comment: thanks, that looks very useful

Comment: While information at this link may answer the question, currently [_this_ is not an answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259). Please consider including the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.